# Openlayers draw multiple coordinates off KML data coming from the database

Tags: openlayers-2

I am a pure beginner of openlayers, I have a KML data coming from the database which describes all the cordinates of zip code 45050, I would like to draw these coordinates onto openlayers map as boundaries and I want it colored as well.
I am not pretty sure that my KML data is appropriate. Is there any easy way to do so? if so would you expose the solution.

Here is my KML data:
-84.3398,39.4274,0 -84.3535,39.4283,0 -84.3539,39.4239,0 -84.3589,39.4241,0 -84.3661,39.4256,0 -84.3658,39.4287,0 -84.3838,39.4298,0 -84.3834,39.4336,0 -84.3783,39.4333,0 -84.3786,39.4338,0 -84.3836,39.437,0 -84.3941,39.4376,0 -84.3985,39.4418,0 -84.3932,39.4571,0 -84.393,39.465,0 -84.3934,39.4738,0 -84.389,39.4714,0 -84.39,39.4666,0 -84.3725,39.4679,0 -84.3649,39.4644,0 -84.3536,39.4632,0 -84.3527,39.464,0 -84.3491,39.4622,0 -84.337,39.4521,0 -84.337,39.4521,0 -84.3398,39.4274,0

Comment: That is not KML.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/vector-formats.html) of what you are looking for.

To use it, choose KML as the format, paste your kml into the box, and click "add feature". You will see the kml is fine as I have it below:

```xml
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <Folder>
        <name>OpenLayers export</name>
        <description>Exported on Thu Jan 17 2013 16:40:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)</description>
        <Placemark>
            <name>OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_116</name><description>No description available</description>
            <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-84.3398, 39.4274 -84.3535, 39.4283 -84.3539, 39.4239 -84.3589, 39.4241 -84.3661, 39.4256 -84.3658, 39.4287 -84.3838, 39.4298 -84.3834, 39.4336 -84.3783, 39.4333 -84.3786, 39.4338 -84.3836, 39.437 -84.3941, 39.4376 -84.3985, 39.4418 -84.3932, 39.4571 -84.393, 39.465 -84.3934, 39.4738 -84.389, 39.4714 -84.39, 39.4666 -84.3725, 39.4679 -84.3649, 39.4644 -84.3536, 39.4632 -84.3527, 39.464 -84.3491, 39.4622 -84.337, 39.4521 -84.337, 39.4521 -84.3398, 39.4274</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Folder>
</kml/>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, now how do I get the js code to implement this and draw it? how do I change the color?for instance I have 2 or multiple zip codes and I want to draw them in different colors

Comment: The code to implement it is in [the example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/vector-formats.html), please view source. You can change the color by using the feature styles. Many ways to do it. Please refer to the [styling guide](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html).